# SFML/C++: I can't make the object fall at the correct velocity down the screen. It falls at the correct velocity when drop_ht is 100 & obj_mass is 1

Tags: c++, sfml

So basically this is a little program I am making that simulates an object falling from a chosen height with a given mass. It is supposed to fall down the window at a velocity that matches the fall time.

I have been racking my brains and I cannot get it to work correctly with any other drop_ht {100} and obj_mass {1.0}.

I thought I was on the right track by dividing the screen by drop height to get the "pixels per meter" but whenever I increase the drop_ht the fall velocity increases.

For example: drop_ht = 100 and obj_mass = 1 the fall_time is 16.1 seconds. Currently the object does takes 16.1 seconds to fall down the window. But if I double the drop_ht too 200 it only takes around 8 seconds too fall.

PS. I know some of this the calculations aren't fully optimised along with other things but this is still a work in progress! :)

This is the main file:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "inputs.h"
#include "ball_drop.h" 
#include "calculations.h"


int main()
{
    double x_res{ 1000.f };
    double y_res{ 800.f };
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(x_res, y_res), "Freefall Calculator");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    double x_middle{ x_res / 2.0 };
    double y_midlle{ y_res / 2.0 };

    /*------------------------------------*/
    /* Create text to display on screen   */
    /*------------------------------------*/
    sf::Font arial;
    if (!arial.loadFromFile("fonts\\arial.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load font file.";
    }

    sf::Text menu_text;
    menu_text.setFont(arial);
    //menu_text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    menu_text.setOutlineThickness(0.5);

    std::vector <std::string> welcome_text;
    welcome_text.push_back("Welcome to Freefall Calculator!");
    welcome_text.push_back("Please choose the object you would like to drop....");

    std::vector <std::string> obj_selection_txt;
    obj_selection_txt.push_back("Cube selected!");
    obj_selection_txt.push_back("Ball selected!");

    int welcome_vec_size = welcome_text.size()-1; 
    
    /* Used to iterate through different pages of the application */
    int next_display{ 0 };   

    /* Text for object selection */
    sf::Vector2f cube_text_pos(230.0, 500.0);
    sf::Vector2f ball_text_pos(640.0, 500.0);
    sf::Text object_text;
    object_text.setFont(arial);
    //object_text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    object_text.setString("Cube");
    object_text.setPosition(cube_text_pos);
    
    /* Text for pressing space bar */
    sf::Text press_space;
    press_space.setFont(arial);
    //press_space.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    press_space.setString("Push space to continue...");
    press_space.setPosition(320, 700);

    /* User input text */
    sf::Text user_text;
    user_text.setFont(arial);
    sf::String user_input;

    /* User input page */
    int next_text_input{ 0 }; // changes input selection

    sf::Text get_drop_ht;
    get_drop_ht.setFont(arial);
    //get_drop_ht.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    get_drop_ht.setPosition(0, 0);
    get_drop_ht.setString("Enter drop height (Meters):");

    sf::Text input_drop_ht;
    input_drop_ht.setFont(arial);
    input_drop_ht.setPosition(400, 0);
    input_drop_ht.setString("I");
    std::string drop_ht_string;

    sf::Text get_obj_mass;
    get_obj_mass.setFont(arial);
    //get_obj_mass.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    get_obj_mass.setPosition(0, 300);
    get_obj_mass.setString("Enter object mass (KG):");

    sf::Text input_obj_mass;
    input_obj_mass.setFont(arial);
    input_obj_mass.setPosition(400, 300);
    std::string obj_mass_string;

    
    /*----------------------------------*/
    /* Load in textures for objects     */
    /*----------------------------------*/
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    
    sf::Texture concrete;
    if (!concrete.loadFromFile("textures\\concrete_texture.jpg"))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load concrete texture\n";
    }

    sf::Texture crate;
    if (!crate.loadFromFile("textures\\crate_texture.jpg"))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load crate texture\n";
    }

    sf::Texture backgorund_texture;
    if (!backgorund_texture.loadFromFile("textures\\sky_bg.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load background texture\n";
    }
    
    sf::Texture cloud_texture;
    if (!cloud_texture.loadFromFile("textures\\cloud.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot load clout texture\n";
    }
    
    /*----------------------*/
    /* Create menu objects  */
    /*----------------------*/
    sf::CircleShape menu_ball;
    menu_ball.setRadius(75);
    sf::Vector2f menu_ball_pos(600, 300);
    menu_ball.setPosition(menu_ball_pos);
    menu_ball.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    menu_ball.setOutlineThickness(0.0);
    menu_ball.setTexture(&concrete);

    sf::Vector2f ff_ball_pos(x_middle, 0);

    sf::RectangleShape menu_cube;
    menu_cube.setSize(sf::Vector2f(150.f, 150.f));
    sf::Vector2f menu_cube_pos(200, 300);
    menu_cube.setPosition(menu_cube_pos);
    menu_cube.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    menu_cube.setOutlineThickness(10.0);
    menu_cube.setTexture(&crate);
    sf::Vector2f ff_cube_pos(x_middle, 0);

    std::vector <float> cube_size(60.f, 60.f);
    float ball_rad{ 30.f };

    /*-------------------------*/
    /* Creates menu background */
    /*-------------------------*/
    sf::Sprite background_image;
    background_image.setScale(1,1);
    background_image.setTexture(backgorund_texture);
    //background_image.setColor(sf::Color::Blue);

    sf::Sprite cloud;
    cloud.setTexture(cloud_texture);
    cloud.setScale(0.1, 0.1);
    
    /*---------------------*/
    /*   Main Objects      */
    /*---------------------*/
    int object_chosen {0};
    double drop_ht {}; // drop ht for maths
    double obj_mass{}; // object mass for maths

    double fall_velocity{};
    double rel_screen_drop_ht{};
    double fall_time{};

    const float time_delta{ 0.1 };

    /*--------------------*/
    /*   Time Objects     */
   /*---------------------*/
    sf::Clock mass_input_clock;
    bool obj_mass_input_clock_start{ false };

    sf::Clock text_cursor_clock;
    bool text_cursor_clock_start{ false };
    int switch_text_cursor_colour{ 0 };

    sf::Clock freefall_clock;
    bool freefall_clock_start{ false };


    /*---------------------*/
    /*   main event loop   */
    /*---------------------*/
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }   
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            {
                window.close();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
                {
                    /* This changes to the object selection menu */
                    if (next_display < 1) 
                    {
                        next_display = 1;
                    }
                    /* Cube chosen */ 
                    else if (object_chosen == 0 && next_display == 1)
                    {
                            menu_text.setString(obj_selection_txt[0]);
                            menu_text.setCharacterSize(75);                            
                            menu_cube.setOutlineThickness(0);
                            next_display = 2;
                    }
                    /* Ball Chosen */
                    else if (object_chosen == 1 && next_display == 1)
                    {
                        menu_text.setString(obj_selection_txt[1]);
                        menu_text.setCharacterSize(75);                   
                        menu_ball.setOutlineThickness(0);
                        next_display = 2;
                    }
                    /* Goes to next text input when drop_ht string length is > 0 */
                    else if ((next_display == 3) && (drop_ht_string.length() > 0) && (next_text_input == 0))
                    {
                        next_text_input = 1;
                        input_drop_ht.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
                        input_obj_mass.setString("I");
                        text_cursor_clock_start = true;
                    }
                    else if ((next_text_input == 1) && (obj_mass_string.length() > 0))
                    {
                        mass_input_clock.restart();
                        input_obj_mass.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
                        obj_mass_input_clock_start = true;

                        menu_ball.setPosition(ff_ball_pos);
                        menu_cube.setPosition(ff_cube_pos);

                        menu_ball.setRadius(ball_rad);
                        menu_cube.setSize(sf::Vector2f::Vector2(cube_size[0], cube_size[1]));
                        
                        //debug use of calculation functions
                        fall_time = calculate_free_fall_time(obj_mass, drop_ht);
                        
                        //calculate_distance_fallen(drop_ht, fall_time);                       
                        
                        fall_velocity = obj_fall_velocity(fall_time, drop_ht, y_res);
                        
                        std::cout << "fall velocity = " << fall_velocity << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "drop height = " << drop_ht << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "fall time = " << fall_time << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                /* Alows user to backaspace to delete text inputs */
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::BackSpace)
                {
                    if (next_text_input == 0)
                    { 
                        input_drop_ht.setString(erase_text(drop_ht_string));                      
                    }
                    else if (next_text_input == 1)
                    {
                        input_obj_mass.setString(erase_text(obj_mass_string));
                    }
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                {
                    if (next_display == 1)
                    {
                        menu_ball.setOutlineThickness(10.0);
                        menu_cube.setOutlineThickness(0.0);
                        object_text.setString("Ball");
                        object_text.setPosition(ball_text_pos);
                        object_chosen = 1;
                            std::cout << "ball chosen\n";
                    }
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                {
                    if (next_display == 1)
                    {
                        menu_ball.setOutlineThickness(0.0);
                        menu_cube.setOutlineThickness(10.0);
                        object_text.setString("Cube");
                        object_text.setPosition(cube_text_pos);
                        object_chosen = 0;
                            std::cout << "cube chosen\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) && (next_display == 3))
            {
                if (next_text_input == 0)
                {
                    if (event.text.unicode >= 48 && event.text.unicode <= 57)
                    {
                        //std::cout << "ASCII character typed: " << static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode) << std::endl; 
                        text_cursor_clock_start = false;
                        input_drop_ht.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
                        drop_ht_string += event.text.unicode;                     
                        input_drop_ht.setString(drop_ht_string);
                        drop_ht = std::stod(drop_ht_string);                       
                    }
                }
                else if (next_text_input == 1)
                {
                    if (event.text.unicode >= 48 && event.text.unicode <= 57)
                    {
                        //std::cout << "ASCII character typed: " << static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode) << std::endl;
                        text_cursor_clock_start = false;
                        input_obj_mass.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
                        obj_mass_string += event.text.unicode;
                        input_obj_mass.setString(obj_mass_string);
                        obj_mass = std::stod(obj_mass_string);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        /*************************************/
        /****** Display specific events ******/
        /*************************************/
        
        /* Changes the font size and text position for menu text */
        if (next_display == 0)
        {
            menu_text.setPosition(165, 300);
            menu_text.setCharacterSize(50);
            menu_text.setString(welcome_text[0]);
        }
        else if (next_display == 1)
        {
            menu_text.setPosition(165, 0);
            menu_text.setCharacterSize(30);
            menu_text.setString(welcome_text[1]);
        }

        /* Changes the y pos of object when it has been selected to make 
           it drop from the screen */
        else if (next_display == 2)
        {
            float menu_drop_velocity{ 10 };
            menu_text.setPosition(250, 0);
            menu_cube_pos.y += menu_drop_velocity;
            menu_ball_pos.y += menu_drop_velocity;
            menu_cube.setPosition(menu_cube_pos);
            menu_ball.setPosition(menu_ball_pos);
            //std::cout << menu_ball_pos.y << std::endl;
            if ((menu_ball_pos.y  > y_res) || (menu_cube_pos.y > y_res))
            {
                next_display = 3;
                text_cursor_clock_start = true;
            }
        }
        else if (next_display == 3)
        {
            
            /*************************/
            /****** Time Events ******/
            /*************************/
            
            // This handles the delay when the object mass has been inputted to //
            // allow the text enough time to go green before changing to the    //
            // object drop animation.                                          //
            if (obj_mass_input_clock_start)
            {
                sf::Time obj_seconds_passed = mass_input_clock.getElapsedTime();
                sf::Time obj_seconds = sf::seconds(1.f);
                if (obj_seconds_passed > obj_seconds)
                {
                    /*menu_ball.setPosition(ff_ball_pos);
                    menu_cube.setPosition(ff_cube_pos);

                    menu_ball.setRadius(10.f);
                    menu_cube.setSize(sf::Vector2f::Vector2(10.f, 10.f));*/
                    //freefall_clock.restart();

                    next_display = 4;
                    freefall_clock_start = true;
                    freefall_clock.restart();
                }
            }
            
            // This handles the text cursor pulsating from white to black. Pulse //
            // frequency can be changed by editted "text_cursor_pulse_seconds"  //
            if (text_cursor_clock_start)
            {
                sf::Time cursor_time_passed = text_cursor_clock.getElapsedTime();
                sf::Time text_cursor_pulse_seconds = sf::seconds(0.5f);
               
                if ((cursor_time_passed > text_cursor_pulse_seconds) && (switch_text_cursor_colour == 0))
                {
                    switch_text_cursor_colour = 1;
                    
                    if (next_text_input == 0)
                    {
                        input_drop_ht.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
                    }
                    else if (next_text_input == 1)
                    {
                        input_obj_mass.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
                    }
                    text_cursor_clock.restart();
                }
                else if ((cursor_time_passed > text_cursor_pulse_seconds) && (switch_text_cursor_colour == 1))
                {
                    switch_text_cursor_colour = 0;
                    
                    if (next_text_input == 0)
                    {
                        input_drop_ht.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
                    }
                    else if (next_text_input == 1)
                    {
                        input_obj_mass.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
                    }
                    text_cursor_clock.restart();
                }
                //std::cout << cursor_time_passed.asSeconds() << std::endl;
                //std::cout << "switch colour: " << switch_text_cursor_colour << std::endl;
            }
            
        }
        else if (next_display == 4)
        {
            if (freefall_clock_start == true)
            {
                sf::Time ff_timer = freefall_clock.getElapsedTime();
                
                std::cout << ff_timer.asSeconds() << std::endl; // debug 

                ff_cube_pos.y += fall_velocity;
                ff_ball_pos.y += fall_velocity;
                menu_cube.setPosition(ff_cube_pos);
                menu_ball.setPosition(ff_ball_pos);

                if ((ff_ball_pos.y == (y_res - (ball_rad *2))) || (ff_cube_pos.y > (y_res - cube_size[0])))
                {
                    freefall_clock_start = false;
                    //freefall_clock.restart();
                }
            }       
        }   
        /*******************************/
        
        /*---------------------*/
        /*   Main draw block   */
        /*---------------------*/
        window.clear();
        //window.draw(background_image);
        
        /* Application welcoms page */
        if (next_display == 0)
        {
            //window.draw(cloud);
            window.draw(menu_text);
            window.draw(press_space);   
        }
        // Object selection page
        else if (next_display == 1)
        {
            window.draw(menu_text);
            window.draw(menu_ball);
            window.draw(menu_cube);
            window.draw(object_text); 
            window.draw(press_space);
        }
        /* Object selected page */
        else if (next_display == 2)
        {
            window.draw(menu_text);
            if (object_chosen == 0)
            {
                window.draw(menu_cube);
            }
            else
            {
                window.draw(menu_ball);
            }
        }
        /* User input page */
        else if (next_display == 3)
        {
            window.draw(press_space);
            window.draw(get_drop_ht);
            window.draw(get_obj_mass);
            window.draw(input_drop_ht);
            window.draw(input_obj_mass);
            //window.draw(text_cursor);
        } 
        else if (next_display == 4)
        {                        
            //window.draw(background_image);
            //window.draw(cloud);
            if (object_chosen == 0)
            {
                window.draw(menu_cube);
            }
            else if (object_chosen == 1)
            {
                window.draw(menu_ball);


            }
        }
        window.display();
       
        /* debug cout */

        //std::cout << "next text: " << next_text << std::endl;
        //std::cout << drop_ht << std::endl;
        //std::cout << obj_mass << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the file where the calculations are done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

#include "calculations.h"

const double g{ 9.80665 };   // Gravity (m/s2)
const double p{ 1.2041 };    // Density of air (kg/m3)
const double e{ 2.71828 };   // Euler's number (e)
const double k{ 0.24 };      // Air resistance (kg/m)
const double pi{ 3.142 };    // Pi

// Calculate free fall time
double calculate_free_fall_time(double mass, double height)
{
    double freefall_time{ (sqrt(mass / (g * k))) * (acosh(pow(e,(height * k) / mass))) };
    return freefall_time;
}

// Calculate object fall velocity on screen
double obj_fall_velocity(double fall_time, double drop_ht, double screen_ht)
{
    
    double pix_per_meter = drop_ht / screen_ht;

    return (drop_ht / fall_time) * pix_per_meter;
}
```

The the problem lies with the "obj_fall_velocity" function. I have tried many variations of dividing the screen height by the drop height to get the pixels per meter.

```
// Calculate object fall velocity on screen
double obj_fall_velocity(double fall_time, double drop_ht, double screen_ht)
{
    
    double pix_per_meter = drop_ht / screen_ht;

    return (drop_ht / fall_time) * pix_per_meter;
}
```

Currently if the inputs to this function are (16.1, 100, 800) the object falls down the screen in 16 seconds but if they are (31.2, 200, 800) It falls down the screen in around 8 seconds.

I just don't understand... I have probably been staring this for too long now.

Comment: Surely ```pix_per_meter = drop_ht / screen_ht;``` should be ```pix_per_meter = screen_ht / drop_ht```. Also, you are only going to get an average velocity over the drop: this doesn't correspond to your formulae, which assume a non-constant velocity based on a net downward force mg-kv^2. Finally, ```pow(e,(height * k) / mass)``` is more naturally ```exp(height * k / mass)```.

Comment: the same issue exists if it is:

 double pix_per_meter = screen_ht / drop_ht;

 return (drop_ht / fall_time) / pix_per_meter;

Thank you for the simplified formula.

Comment: Obviously that issue will continue to exist if you then go on to change a * (multiply) to a / (divide) when applying that function! I only invited you to make one change, not two. Just make the entire function ```return screen_ht/fall_time;```, then you should circumvent the problem.

Comment: Changing the whole function to `return screen_ht/fall_time` doesn't solve the issue at all as it is no longer converting the the screen height to the inputted drop height. 

Doing that just makes the object drop in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Your object fall velocity should be unrelated to the screen height in pixels anyway. The average fall velocity should be just ```drop_ht / fall_time```. If this was correct for one drop_height and mass then it should be correct for any other one as well. I would stop playing with the screen_ht here, since it has nothing to do with the physics of falling particles. I also repeat: distance / time will just give you an average velocity; your simulation is for one for which velocity is not constant, although it tends to a terminal velocity sqrt(mg/k).

Answer (score 0):

What i think the problem is in your code is the logic behind what you're actually calculating. I went through your code, and i wont lie i was kind of lost at some points so correct me if im wrong but your code seems to calculate or at least act to move the block in a linear pattern completely differently from what it technically should be. That being said i tried working on your code but it became a little bit too overly complicated so i opted for a clean and fresh new project to show you the premise of what you should do to attaiin the correct values. Im going to assume from now on that what you want is the real world simulation of free fall of an object with air resistance in time.

The problem i think your code has lies in the calculation of the y position for the box or circle to be on screen. I think that somewhere in the calculation it turns this unlinear system into a linear one thus why you're having a problem (among small other things). I rewrote your functions and added some more new ones just to make the code cleaner:

```cpp
// Calculate free fall time
double calculate_free_fall_time(double mass, double height)
{
    double freefall_time{ (sqrt(mass / (g * k))) * (acosh(pow(e,(height * k) / mass))) };
    return freefall_time;
}
```

This free fall time function i left alone. it's good. good work.

```cpp
double calculate_velocity(double fall_time, double mass)
{
    double vel = (sqrt(mass*g/k)*tanh(fall_time/sqrt(mass/g/k)));
    return vel;
}
```

This above one calculated the velocity in specific time.

```cpp
double calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(double fall_time, double mass)
{
    double height = mass/k*log(cosh(fall_time/sqrt(mass/g/k)));
    return height;
}
```

And this one i think is the most important one you lacked, which is the calculation of distance travelled by object in given time.

All these formulas were found on website and calculator:
https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224830797
[image: Picture of formulas]

Now why add these functions? I think it'd be easiest way to calculate where when and how the object's movements shoul happen. Knowing the distance travelled by objects means you also know where to put it on your screen at every single moment.
Why couldnt we just use some simple a = b method to move the object? because the system is nonlinear and it accelerates before it reaches constant speed, if we had a constant speed from start it would ruin everything including time, distance and so on.

Now onto gluing all this together:

```cpp
// Calculate object fall velocity on screen
double obj_fall_pos(sf::RectangleShape &box, double mass, double drop_ht, double screen_ht, double fall_time)
{
    //lets assume u drop box from top to bottom of screen. this function will calculate the y
    //max screen = screen ht
    //max distance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time();
    //we combine the two to get a percentage = screen/distance
    //multiply it by current distance made.
    double maxFallTime = calculate_free_fall_time(mass, drop_ht);
    double maxDistance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(maxFallTime, mass);
    double maxVelocity = calculate_velocity(maxFallTime, mass);
    if (fall_time > maxFallTime) fall_time = maxFallTime;
    double currentDistance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(fall_time, mass);
    double currentVelocity = calculate_velocity(fall_time,mass);
    double y = currentDistance / maxDistance * screen_ht;
    cout << "MaxFallTime: " << maxFallTime << endl
         << "MaxDistance: " << maxDistance << endl
         << "MaxVelocity: " << maxVelocity << endl
         << "CurrentDistance: " << currentDistance << endl
           << "CurrentVelocity: " << currentVelocity << endl
         << "yPos: " << y << endl;
    cout << currentVelocity << endl;
    box.setPosition(box.getPosition().x, y);
    return y;
}
```

We can now use these functions to calculate everything we need. We first calculate where the object should stop by finding its max distance. Knowing that we can calculate the position on screen of what it should be by simple percentages calculation via screensize, max distance and current distance.

If there are any problems or if you have questions or if i did anything wrong let me know. Hope this helps.

Below is the full code of implementation which you can implement into your own project the way you have it by just substituting your functions with these and changing the logic a little bit to accomodate for the changes in the functions.

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//#include "inputs.h"
//#include "ball_drop.h"
//#include "calculations.h"

const double g{ 9.80665 };   // Gravity (m/s2)
const double p{ 1.2041 };    // Density of air (kg/m3)
const double e{ 2.71828 };   // Euler's number (e)
const double k{ 0.24 };      // Air resistance (kg/m)
const double pi{ 3.142 };    // Pi

// Calculate free fall time
double calculate_free_fall_time(double mass, double height)
{
    double freefall_time{ (sqrt(mass / (g * k))) * (acosh(pow(e,(height * k) / mass))) };
    return freefall_time;
}

double calculate_velocity(double fall_time, double mass)
{
    double vel = (sqrt(mass*g/k)*tanh(fall_time/sqrt(mass/g/k)));
    return vel;
}

double calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(double fall_time, double mass)
{
    double height = mass/k*log(cosh(fall_time/sqrt(mass/g/k)));
    return height;
}

// Calculate object fall velocity on screen
double obj_fall_pos(sf::RectangleShape &box, double mass, double drop_ht, double screen_ht, double fall_time)
{
    //lets assume u drop box from top to bottom of screen. this function will calculate the y
    //max screen = screen ht
    //max distance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time();
    //we combine the two to get a percentage = screen/distance
    //multiply it by current distance made.
    double maxFallTime = calculate_free_fall_time(mass, drop_ht);
    double maxDistance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(maxFallTime, mass);
    double maxVelocity = calculate_velocity(maxFallTime, mass);
    if (fall_time > maxFallTime) fall_time = maxFallTime;
    double currentDistance = calculate_Distance_Travelled_In_Time(fall_time, mass);
    double currentVelocity = calculate_velocity(fall_time,mass);
    double y = currentDistance / maxDistance * screen_ht;
    cout << "MaxFallTime: " << maxFallTime << endl
         << "MaxDistance: " << maxDistance << endl
         << "MaxVelocity: " << maxVelocity << endl
         << "CurrentDistance: " << currentDistance << endl
           << "CurrentVelocity: " << currentVelocity << endl
         << "yPos: " << y << endl;
    cout << currentVelocity << endl;
    box.setPosition(box.getPosition().x, y);
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "My window");
    sf::RectangleShape box({50,50});

    sf::Clock clock;
    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        obj_fall_pos(box,50,100,750,clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()/1000.0);
        cout << clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() << endl;

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        window.draw(box);
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```